# Android editting text file and saving strings to sharedpreferences

Tags: android, arrays, string, sharedpreferences, text-files

Ive managed to implement this into my code and get it to work, however my values are coming like this: 10.020.0, how can i put a space between 10.0 and 20.0 so it comes 10.0 20.0

Also if someone could help me figure out an alternative way to save this into a specific sharedpreferences file, instead of the default, so for example a stats sharedpreferences and retrieve the values in another activity in a table? Ive given it a go, but am not sure if it works in the same way, i need the sharedpreferences to work in the same way as the text file. Im using the text file as i can view the file whereas sharedpreferences im unable to see whats going on.

SharedPreference attempt:

```
public void AddStringSavedPreference(){

    SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("StatsPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    Set<String> statsStrings = settings.getStringSet("statsStrings", new HashSet<String>());

    statsStrings.add(Double.toString(weight));

    editor.putStringSet("statsStrings", statsStrings);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the file, if you want spaces in between weights, add a space when writing to file.

Change this:

```
osw.write(Double.toString(weight));
```

to this:

```
osw.write(Double.toString(weight) + " ");
```

It will result in: `10.0 20.0`. Something to be aware of is that now there is going to be a space after the last weight in the file and you will need to account for it when you are reading the file.

Shared preferences look ok to me. For seeing the values, either add a breakpoint and debug your program, or add logging and look at Logcat to see the values in the logs - the logcat view usually appears automatically, but if it doesn't, it will depend from whether you are using Android Studio or Eclipse on how to open it. It can also be seen through command line. This might help: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html  For the logging example, using your code:

```
SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("StatsPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
Set<String> statsStrings = settings.getStringSet("statsStrings", new HashSet<String>());

statsStrings.add(Double.toString(weight));

// log takes a tag as first value, which can be any value, usually application name
Log.d("MyApplication", "Adding following values: " + statsStrings.toString());

editor.putStringSet("statsStrings", statsStrings);
editor.commit();
```

Retrieving values. Again, adding a log will help to see the values:

```
SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("StatsPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> statsStrings = settings.getStringSet("statsStrings", new HashSet<String>());
Log.d("MyApplication", "Retrieved following values: " + statsStrings.toString());
```

Comment: Ill edit my main post to show you whats going on, i have a default shared preference but i want to put these in another just so i know its working.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure whether I completely understand what you are attempting to do. You can have different SharedPreferences if you prefer to organise your code that way. As long as you call the same preference name and the same name of value added to that preference when you are adding and removing the values, that is fine.

Comment: I just want the sharedpreference to work in the same way as this text file, so it adds the string into arrays in the sharedpreference. Then i can call it without the space causing any trouble. Hope that makes more sense. Also want to know how i can visually see the values entered since i cant access a sharedpreference file

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I get what you want to do now. :) I have edited the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Cheers ill try this tomorrow, too tired now haha thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep works :D Adding following values: [120.0, 115.0, 130.0, 140.0, 135.0]

Comment: Having one problem, when i exit the application and relaunch it, the values which were saved are being removed and is only displaying the first string that was saved, any help?